# IF statement within multiple FOR loop

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and confused with nesting a `if` function within a `for loop`

I only want the `for loop` to continue based on the return value from the `if`.

In this case, I'm looking to iterate over all Message`s in an inbox, if their read value is False iterate over the attachments of Messages that are not read..

However, using the below I keep getting all attachments saved regardless of their read value being `True` or `False`

```
for Message in mail_folders.get_messages():
    if Message.is_read == False:
        for att in Message.attachments:
            if '.html' in att.name:
                att.save(sv_path)
```

have I completly written this wrong? or are my indents incorrect?

**Update**

Using

```
for Message in mail_folders.get_messages():
    print(Message.is_read)
    if Message.is_read == False:
        for att in Message.attachments:
            if '.html' in att.name:
                att.save(sv_path)
```

The print statement returns `True` & `False` value

thanks

Comment: what library are you using? Is this Win32?

Comment: Are you sure `Message.is_read` is a property **and** it returns a boolean value? Print its value before the first `if` to confirm that.

Comment: `if Message.is_read == False:`, this statement will be only executed if is.read return false hence `false==false`, you need to check what is the value being returned by .is_read.

Comment: @Hofbr o365 library https://github.com/O365/python-o365

Comment: i didn't find any method called as .is_read in the documentation

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Try https://o365.github.io/python-o365/latest/html/api/message.html

Comment: Your indentation is correct and there is no reason for your code to not work. You must be missing something else (such as having the same attachment attached to different messages).

Comment: I couldn't find info in the documentation, but there is an is_read property in the codebase that says in the comment it returns a bool value.
https://github.com/O365/python-o365/blob/8b09383b1d27faf3997b7a83949a14265fa055fa/O365/message.py#L770

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why but making two changes it is now working.

```
for m in mail_folders.get_messages(download_attachments = True):
    print(m.is_read)
    if m.is_read == False:
        for att in m.attachments:
            if '.html' in att.name:
                att.save(sv_path)
```

Comment: The only change of note i see is the (download_attachments=True).